# Как проще всего перехватить и обработать web страницу в браузере или до него?

Tags: веб-программирование

**Постановка задачи**

При открытии сайтов в браузере требуется провести предварительную обработку контента и, поменяв содержимое страницы, показать её в бразуере. То есть всё происходит у клиента, а не на сервере.

**Пример**

Найти на странице определённый текст и выделить его рамкой или указать стрелкой.

**Дополнительные условия**

Код, который обрабатывает контент, находится во внешнем приложении. Скажем, С++. То есть хотелось бы как-то передать данные в приложение (через файл?) и получив обновлённую страницу, показать её пользователю.
Предположим, что браузер FireFox, хотя вполне может быть, что это не важно.
OS - Windows.

**Мой вариант решения**

WebExtensions / выгрузка в файл / загрузка ответа / подмена страницы. Пока не уверен, что это реализуемо и что хватит API.

**Альтернатива**

Сделать какой-то proxy, где всё это делать, но не знаю какой.
Если бы у меня была возможность в WinAPI написать hook для перехвата html-текста и возможности его подмены - это было бы, наверное, самым простым для меня решением.

**Вопрос**

Какой самый простой способ решить такую задачу?

Буду благодарен, если укажете на какой-то пример.

Comment: Сразу напрашивается: собрать HTTP-прокси.

Comment: Возможно вам просто необходимо сделать расширение для браузера, это наиболее просто делается, при этом будет работать как http так и с https

Answer (score 0):

[Расширения для браузера](https://habrahabr.ru/post/198652/) можно делать на JavaScript, который предоставляет массу возможностей [для работы с DOM](https://learn.javascript.ru/dom-nodes). Это именно то что нужно для поиска и подсвечивая текста.

Если рука на JavaScript не набита, а сделать нужно много и поскорее, лучше изучить (да не обрушится кара на мою голову) [jQuery](https://professorweb.ru/my/javascript/jquery/level1/1_2.php). Это JavaScript библиотека, которая помогает выполнять ходовые задачи набирая минимум кода.

Альтернативный способ (я про прокси на C++) интересен своей сложностью, но требует опыта, усидчивости, и знаний (не только лишь C++ , но и веб протоколов, парсеров, регулярных выражения и прочего). При желании, начать наверное лучше с изучения готовых реализаций на GitHub или подобных ресурсах как примеров. Их много, можно наверное даже что нибудь найти себе как основу.